# Как добавить байт в конец HEX значения?

Tags: c++, c

Нужно из 6-ти битного хекса сделать семибитный путем добавления в конец одного бита.

Прошу помочь с решением вопроса без использования функций и инклюдов так как в моем случае они недоступны.

```c
int hex1 = 0x9821d9;

int hex2 = 0xF3;
int hex2First = (hex2 & 0xF0) >> 4;

int hex3 = // hex1 + hex2First = 0x9821d9F
```

На выходе нужен `int hex3 = 0x9821d9F;`

Comment: `unsigned int hex3 = (hex1 << 4) | hex2First;`

Comment: Только это никакие не биты. Одна цифра в шестнадцатеричном представлении - это 4 бита или полбайта.

Comment: Вечно путаюсь в формулировках

Comment: В этой операции `hex2First = (hex2 & 0xF0) >> 4;` обнуление последних 4 бит `(hex2 & 0xF0)` лишняя операция, т.к. всё равно потом идет сдвиг. Поэтому `(hex2 & 0xF0) >> 4` то же самое, что и `hex2 >> 4`

Comment: четыре бита называется тетрада.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, а еще их зовут [nibble](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%BB)  (По-английски «nibble» означает «покусывать», тогда как «byte» — искажённое «bite», «кусать».)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
unsigned int hex3 = (hex1 << 4) | hex2First;
```

Спасибо [maestro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3380/maestro)!